Rust Multithreading Freezing with Serial Ports
I've been working on a rust project to communicate to an Arduino through serial port.  I've found a few cargo dependencies that do the trick.  But with the few I have tested, they have this same problem:
I want to have a thread spawned so that it can be blocked for any coming data the Arduino sends at any given moment. With another thread get an input from the user (e.g. from console input) and send that to the Arduino, thus having 2 threads running simultaneously.  But with that running, while the thread that's waiting for data from the Arduino, once I give an input, the thread that is supposed to write to the Arduino just freezes at the method.
Here is sample code using the serialport crate:
use std::{
    io::{stdin, stdout, Read, Write},
    thread,
};

fn main() {
    let mut port = serialport::new("COM5", 9600).open().unwrap();
    let r_port = port.try_clone().unwrap();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        for rb in r_port.bytes() {
            // I've used all the read methods in their respective matter, but the write method still gets stuck no matter what.
            match rb {
                Ok(byte) => {
                    print!("{}", byte as char);
                    stdout().flush().unwrap();
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("{e}");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        port.write(input.as_bytes()).unwrap(); // thread gets stuck here
    }
}

Yes, I made sure the com number was correct and the baud rate was consistent.
Any help is very much appreciated!

I stumbled across this issue as well in a project of mine. I worked around this issue by not cloning the SerialPort, but rather wrapping it inside a Mutex.

I just played around with it again, and it appears, that using an explicit TTYPort on Linux and cloning it via try_clone_native() also works, i.e. does not result in a deadlock.

For the Mutex part, can you show me what you did?  I'm a little confused since you can't clone a Mutex...maybe I don't know how mutex works fully.  I used Arc to wrap the Mutex, but the thread still gets stuck.

This was the code before the change: https://github.com/PaulmannLighting/ashv2/blob/8d8f7a492172b10455337d93a94805705eed83d2/src/host.rs#L47

I also used a timeout to prevent the receiver thread from blocking too long.

So I did try the TTYPort with UNIX and that works without deadlocks.  But trying it with COMPort on windows still gets stuck.  Even trying with Arc and Mutex gets stuck.

I would say, setting a duration to like 5 seconds, TTYPort seems to be able to send while the other thread is waiting for data, but COMPort makes it stuck until the timeout happens.

I would use an Arc<Mutex> to share access to the serialport. It's maybe not the most performant way and also not the best way to do it, but I guess it's the least effort - just to get started.
(The best way would probably be to use one channel for reading and one channel for writing and maybe to use async methods from Tokio).
use std::{
    io::{stdin, stdout, Read, Write},
    thread,
};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut port = Arc::new(Mutex::new(serialport::new("COM5", 9600).open().unwrap()));
    let mut r_port = port.clone();  // create a new atomic ref-counted pointer to port

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            let p = r_port.bytes().lock();  // get access to the Mutexed port
            let num_bytes_to_read = r_port.bytes_to_read();
            if num_bytes_to_read > 0 {
                for rb in r_port.bytes() {
                    match rb {
                        Ok(byte) => {
                            print!("{}", byte as char);
                            stdout().flush().unwrap();
                        }
                        Err(e) => {
                            eprintln!("{e}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            drop(p); // release lock
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));  // make port available for writing for 100ms
       }
    });

    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        let mut p = port.lock();
        p.write(input.as_bytes()).unwrap(); // thread gets stuck here
    }
}

